# Is it possible to override building-wide air-conditioning settings?

Tags: air-conditioning

I live in an apartment building (high rise). The ac is off and they won't turn it on for another month!!

Meanwhile it is 90f inside and I can't sleep!! Is it possible to overide? We do have a unit in the appt with a thermostat and all but only hot air comes out.

Comment: Probably not. Your best bet is some fans, and/or a swamp cooler (if it's humid). Or a window AC if you're allowed to have one. Or start a revolt among the apartment dwellers.

Comment: I'm betting you're on the south side of the building.  This is common.  People on the north side are freezing still.  The best you can do is block the windows.

Answer (score 5):

From inside your apartment, no, the best you can do is use a fan, open the windows, block the sun with blinds, or walk around naked.  And if you do that last part in the building, the management may decide to turn on the AC sooner.

Comment: I bet something would really get done quickly if all the tenants participated in a naked sit-in at the manager's office.